# Check session expiration when using jquery ajax calls

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have a .net core mvc application where I am using the [Authorize] to check if a user's session as expired as well as ensuring a user has the right access to a particular page. This works perfectly fine for the controllers but I need to be able to check if a user's session is expired during a jquery ajax call. I have read many resources on this and have attempted to implement them but they dont seem to work. I am thinking its maybe because majority of the solutions for issue are very outdated.

Can anyone tell me how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Can you elaborate the use case please? Why you need to check the user session?

Comment: I need to check the session because it has an expiration of 10 minutes and it holds a user Id that is used to send data to the database using an ajax request. If that Id is no longer available I want the user to login in again to restart the session.

Comment: You can check session only on server side. You need to check the session and send 401 error back to the client so that client can redirect to login page